# understanding importdata command in matlab

Tags: matlab, import

let us consider following data

```
SunDay  MonDay  TuesDay  WednesDay  ThursDay  FriDay  SatureDay
95.01   76.21   61.54    40.57       55.79    70.28   81.53
73.11   45.65   79.19    93.55       75.29    69.87   74.68
60.68   41.85   92.18    91.69       81.32    90.38   74.51
48.60   82.14   73.82    41.03       0.99     67.22   93.18
89.13   44.47   57.63    89.36       13.89    19.88   46.60
```

let us consider following code

```
filename = 'weeklydata.txt';
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 1;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
% View data
for k = [1:7]
   disp(A.colheaders{1, k})
   disp(A.data(:, k))
   disp(' ')
end
```

i have several question related to this code  ,what does

`headerlinesIn = 1`; and  `disp(A.colheaders{1, k})` do? `for k=[1:7]` is going from sunday to saturday,but this two lines i did not understand and please help  me to clarify it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `headerlinesIn = 1` signalises the `importdata` function, that there is one line to skip at the beginning, which doesn't contain data. It is stored in `A.colheaders`, while your actual data is stored in `A.data`.

With `disp(A.colheaders{1, k})` you now access and display this column headers, for `k=1` the first one.
With `A.data(:, k)` you now access and display the according data of the k-th column,.

So your loop basically prints the header of every column first, then the data of that column and finally an empty line. Then it jumps to the next column.

---

Regarding the comment:
`A.colheaders` contains a cell array with 1 row and 7 columns of strings. `A.colheaders{1, k}` therefore gives you the string of the first row and k-th column. This string is simply displayed `disp(...)`.

Comment: thanks for your help,but related to colheaders,what does it do?

Comment: so that means that SunDay  MonDay  TuesDay  WednesDay  ThursDay  FriDay  SatureDay that corresponds A.colheaders{1)?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? Just type into the command window and you will see. And also in the workspace ;)